# Associative array response to variables with wpdb get results

Tags: arrays, ajax, wordpress, response

I am doing a ajax request which calls a php file which uses wpdb get results.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM t39b_felderkonfig WHERE user_id= %d ",  $user_id), ARRAY_A);
echo json_encode($result);
```

It returns the following array:

```
[{"felderkonfig_id":"7","felderkonfig_kategorie":"1","felderkonfig_kategorie2":"1"]
```

How can i now get the array into variables? I tried:

```
success: function (response) {      
    var kategorie = response['felderkonfig_kategorie'];
    var kategorie2 = response['felderkonfig_kategorie2'];
    var industriesparte = response['felderkonfig_industriesparte'];
```

But that doesnt work.

Solution:
$wpdb get results returns a multidimensional array. To access the array correctly:

```
var kategorie = response[0]['felderkonfig_kategorie'];
```

Maybe this helps other wordpress developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value get issue. Hope this help you

```js
var tmp = [{
  "felderkonfig_id": "7",
  "felderkonfig_kategorie": "1",
  "felderkonfig_kategorie2": "1"
}];
console.log(tmp[0]['felderkonfig_kategorie']);
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date using JSON.parse(). So the response will be passed like this:

`var parseResponse = JSON.parse(response);
var kategorie = parseResponse['felderkonfig_kategorie']`

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. Sadly it doesnt help. I have to put it right below the success: function (response) {... right?